# Segmentation Fault(core dumped) pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc

I have this code but it has an error: Segmentation Fault(core dumped) and it doesn't work with more the 2 threads. Any idea of what am i doing wrong?

This code is for calculate pi by Leibniz formula

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <malloc.h>


#define NUM_HILOS 2

struct datos
{
    int inicio;
    int fin;
    float *pi;
}

*calcPi (void *datos){
    struct datos *datos_proceso;
    datos_proceso = (struct datos *) datos;
    int i = datos_proceso -> inicio;
    int end = datos_proceso -> fin;
    printf("inicio  %d \n", i);
    printf("fin     %d \n", end);   
    float *pi = datos_proceso -> pi;
    int signo = 1;
    do{ 
        *pi = *pi +(signo*4.0)/((2*i)+1);
        i++;
        signo *= -1;
        //printf("%f \n", *pi);
    }while(i<end);
}


int main()
{
    int error, i;
    float *pi;
    int j = -1;
    /*variable para hilos*/
```

I think that the error is over here but i don't know how to fix it

```
    struct datos hilo_datos[NUM_HILOS];
    pthread_t idhilo[NUM_HILOS];
    //printf("este es pi   %f \n", *pi);
    for(i=0; i<NUM_HILOS; i++)
        {
        hilo_datos[i].inicio =j+1;
        hilo_datos[i].fin =j+1000;
        hilo_datos[i].pi = pi;
        printf("%d \n", hilo_datos[i].inicio);
        printf("%d \n", hilo_datos[i].fin);
        j += 1000;
        }

    for(i=0; i<NUM_HILOS; i++)
    {
        error=pthread_create(&idhilo[i], NULL, (void *)calcPi, &hilo_datos[i]);


    }

    for(i=0; i<NUM_HILOS; i++)
        {
        pthread_join(idhilo[i], NULL);
        }
    printf("este es pi   %f \n", *pi);  
return 0;
}
```

Comment: hilo_datos is not an array, so why are you indexing into it?

Comment: Have you tried using GDB to step through your code? I'm pretty sure Martin is right - hilo_datos is a pointer pointing to a memory space enough for only one datos struct. So hilo_datos[0] I think should work but you segfault at hilo_datos[1]. Maybe you wanted to malloc (sizeof (hilo_datos) * NUM_HILOS)?

Comment: Should you call `malloc` like this `struct datos* hilo_datos = (struct datos*) malloc(NUM_HILOS * sizeof (struct datos));)`?

Comment: Seems to me that Martin has a point. You seem to be misallocating your hilo_datos with only a single datos struct, but then you're indexing into this as though it's an array.  This would likely give rise to an segmentation fault.  You probably should just add a  " * NUM_HILOS" to your malloc call, or something like that.

Comment: You should learn how to run a program in GDB (or another debugger). That should point you straight to where you're using `hilo_datos[i]`.

Comment: `hilo_datos[i].pi = pi;`. `pi` is an uninitialised variable. That is, you have not allocated any memory for `pi` and then you dereference it within the thread code.

Comment: Even if `float *pi` and the memory it pointed to *were* correctly initialized, it would still be undefined behavior due to unsynchronized writes to it in multiple threads.

Comment: 1) use a mutex so only a single thread writes to *pi at any one time.  2) this function declaration: `*calcPi (void *datos){` is not correct, it should be: `void *calcPi (void *datos){`

Comment: @FiddlingBits. In C, the returned value from malloc() is type `void*`, which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned type just clutters the code, and can be a real headache when debugging and/or performing maintenance.

Comment: the posted code fails to show the declaration/initialization of 'j'  The posted code fails to set float *pi; to actually point to some allocated memory.  So accessing anything off of `*pi` is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: when working `float` values, all the numbers in the calculations should be `float` but some of the numbers are `double`, like `4.0` and some of the numbers are integers, like `2`.   Note to make a number be a float there are two criteria.  1) the number must have a decimal point  2) the number must have a trailing `'f`.   Suggest using `4.0f` and `2.0f`.

Comment: The posted code fails to compile, for several reasons, including the statement: `#include <stdio.h>` to prototype the `printf()` function

Comment: I see a number of comments about a call to malloc(), but no call to malloc() in the posted code.  This hints that the posted code has been edited.  Strongly suggest when editing code, to open another code block, rather than overlaying the current code block, so the existing comments are still relevant.

Comment: suggest defining the `pi` variable as `volatile` so the compiler picks up the latest value on each access

Comment: @user3629249: This is C, not Java. `volatile != atomic`. Stop giving bad advice.

Comment: @user3629249: C11 draft standard, `5.1.2.4 Multi-threaded executions and data races, Section 4 Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location. [...] Section 25 The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in
different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.` Note the `atomic`? `volatile != atomic`. Don't talk about things you don't know anything about.

Comment: @EOF, pi is a float, I.E. 4 bytes (on a 32 bit architecture) so any read/write operation will be 'atomic'

Comment: @user3629249: Can you read? What part of `undefined behavior` do you not understand?

Comment: @EOF,  I removed some of my prior comments.   However, note that '*p1' is a float and reading/writing a float is a single/atomic event.

Answer (score 2):

Your errors were mainly forgetting simple things like variable initialization.  When a pointer such as `float *pi;` is accessed before being initialized it will almost always cause problems. At the very least it should have raised a compiler warning. By the way, turn on all your compiler warnings.  ***[GCC options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html)***

Here are a few specifics to get a clean build...

***1*** add return statement to calcPi function

```
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

***2*** terminate struct datos with a `;`

```
struct datos {
...
};
 ^
```

***3***  function:

```
* calcPi (void *datos){...}
```

should be:

```
void * calcPi (void *datos){...}
```

Or better:

```
void calcPi (struct datos *d){...} //passing a struct pointer
```

***4*** Initialize your variables before using them. for example:

```
float *pi; //uninitialized
float *pi = NULL;//initialized pointer
pi = malloc(sizeof(float)*NUM_HILOS);//array of pi with NUM_HILOS elements
```

then, in following assignment statements use pi[i], ...

```
hilo_datos[i].pi = pi[i];
```

***Or***, just create a simple float: (you do not need a pointer in this case)

```
float pi = 0;//works just fine for what you are doing
             //no further initialization is needed
```

***Other problems*** include mis-application of threads, creating inappropriate variable types (i.e. for the way you are using it, `float *pi;` could just be `float pi;` negating the need for `malloc()`)

A very simple example of using this algorithm to compute pi (without threading) is included below for illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_HILOS 10   //array elements (no threads)

struct datos //modified for use as array, no threads
{
    float pi;  //PI
};

void calcPi (struct datos *d)
{
    struct datos *datos_proceso = d;
    float pi = datos_proceso[0].pi;
    int signo = 1;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<NUM_HILOS;i++)
    {
        pi = pi + (signo*4.0)/((2*i)+1);
        signo *= -1;
        d[i].pi = pi; //change values for NUM_HILOS to see how 
                      //values for pi converge here. 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int error, i;
    float pi = 0;
    int j = -1;

    //your comment: I think that the error... 
    //... (The error you were seeing here was
    //caused by an uninitialized float *pi; which has been
    //changed to float pi = 0; in this example)

    struct datos hilo_datos[NUM_HILOS];
    for(i=0; i<NUM_HILOS; i++)
    {
        hilo_datos[i].pi = 0; //initialize all to zero
    }

    calcPi(hilo_datos);//send array of struct, check all elelments when returned

    for(i=0; i<NUM_HILOS; i++)
    {
        printf("este es pi   %f \n", hilo_datos[i].pi);    
    }
    getchar();
return 0;
}
```